# Julia NLsolve gives DimensionMismatch-Error when dimension of codomain is larger than dimension of domain

Tags: julia, equation-solving

```
using NLsolve


function g!(G,x)
    G .= [x[1]^2-x[2] for i in 1:3]
end

nlsolve(g!,[0.1, 0.1])
```

This code gives a `DimensionMismatch("array could not be broadcast to match destination")`

When I instead use `G .= [x[1]^2-x[2] for i in 1:2]` I don't get the error. It seems like NLsolve wants th input to be the same size as the output. Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When the number of equations is unequal to the number of variables in linear systems, it's underdetermined (0 or infinite solutions) or overdetermined (0 solutions). Even if equal in a nonlinear system, you may get infinite solutions: sin(x)=0. Your example is actually 1 unique equation with infinite solutions: x^2-y=0; try the 1:2 version with different initial x, you'll get different valid solutions. Maybe the `nlsolve(g!, xi)` method assumes equal number as a "best case." Try asking users on Julia's discourse forum if NLsolve or another package can handle under/over-determined systems.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an `NLsolve` issue, in a fresh Julia session:

```
julia> function g!(G,x)
           G .= [x[1]^2-x[2] for i in 1:3]
       end
g! (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g!([0.0, 0.0], [1.0, 1.0])
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("array could not be broadcast to match destination")
```

Here I am passing `G` with length 2, and then create an array of length 3 on the right hand side. `.=` then tries to write the values created on the right hand side into the left hand side array element-by-element, but the sizes of the arrays are incompatible. Even shorter, you are essentially doing:

```
julia> [0, 0] .= [1, 2, 3]
ERROR: DimensionMismatch("array could not be broadcast to match destination")
```

Comment: But why does NLsolve try to evaluate `g!` with a `G` with length 2? Is there a way to tell NLsolve that the first argument should have length 3 and not 2?

Comment: `nlsolve(g!,[0.1, 0.1])` sets the initial value to an array `[0.1, 0.1]` with length 2, why would you expect `G` to ever have length 3?

Comment: As I understand it, `nlsolve(g!,[0.1, 0.1])` sets the initial value of `x` to `[0.1,0.1]`. I don't know how the length of `G` is inferred. That's why I wondered if you could set it explicitly. It seems to me that Julia incorrectly thinks that `G` has length 2 without any reason.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the problem that you are trying to solve is a Nonlinear Least Squares Problem, not Nonlinear Equations. The main difference between them is you are allowed to have under-determined or over-determined systems in the former, which makes getting the size of your output vector tricky. I recommend going over https://docs.sciml.ai/NonlinearSolve/stable/tutorials/getting_started/, which describes the main differences and how to solve them.

Now, coming to your specific problem.

```
using NonlinearSolve

function g!(G, x, p)  # Note that we need to pass a parameter p for NonlinearSolve.jl
    G[1] = x[1]^2 - x[2]
    G[2] = x[1]^2 - x[2]
    G[3] = x[1]^2 - x[2]
    return nothing
end
```

Now we will creat the function passing `resid_prototype` as zeros(3) which tells NonlinearSolve.jl that the residual vector is of length 3

```
nlf = NonlinearFunction(g!; resid_prototype=zeros(3))
prob = NonlinearLeastSquaresProblem(nlf, [0.1, 0.1])
```

Finally solve it. `solve` by default will choose a robust polyalgorithm, else you can also pass in a solver of your choice from https://docs.sciml.ai/NonlinearSolve/stable/solvers/nonlinear_least_squares_solvers/

```
solve(prob)
```